# Windows 7 won't refresh folder automaticly, made a vbs script to refresh by using Sendkey

Tags: vbscript

Because win7 won't refresh my folder where i store log files, so i found a script online but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sub RefreshSavedFiles()
Dim oShellObject
Set oShellObject = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strFolder = "C:\Users\User\Documents\PDF files saved"
oShellObject.AppActivate strFolder
oShellObject.SendKeys "{F5}"
End Sub
```

i have a backup program that calls this script before it backups the file to my server.

Comment: Can you explain in what way the script does not seem to work? are you getting an error?

Comment: Aside from the fact that `SendKeys` is *very* flaky and should be avoided wherever possible, why would your backup program depend on what folder content is displayed in Windows Explorer? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Do you mean to send an e-mail when a particular file appears in a folder?

Comment: I am pulling errors/alarms from a plc via Putty, these files are stored in a folder on the computer that is connected to the plc. But putty keeps the log file open and adds a new line to it when an alarm/error occurs. Then i use a program called Syncback to backup this log file to a server. Meanwhile there is a sort of kiosk that displays the alarms in real time that are placed over the factory. But because Win7 won't refresh my logfile automaticly. If i press F5 or open the log file, it imediatly pop's up on the kiosk.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your setup, but I think it might be better to check for the presence of the file via [`FileExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t.aspx) and then display a notification or something.

Comment: let me simplefy my explanation of my setup. So Putty is making a log file in a folder. But putty keeps running and adding lines to the log file. But the main problem is that the log file won't update(meaning my timestamp doesn't change) only if i open the log file or the folder were the log file is stored.

Comment: By "timestamp" you mean "date modified"? That's not possible. Refreshing a folder or even reading the file does not modify that timestamp. It only gets updated when a file is written. Explorer may not reflect the change until you refresh, but the timestamp is changed regardless of that. You can verify that via the [`DateLastModified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w.aspx) property of file objects.

Answer (score 0):

This enumerates open folders and refreshes the two specified.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
    For Each window in AllWindows
        If window.locationname = "C:\" or window.locationname = "website2.com" then
            window.refresh2 3
        End If
    Next
```